# Why does this example from the Ember.js guides not work?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I cannot get the second code example of the Ember.js website's Guides section to work. Following [the Simple Routes example](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/getting-started/naming-conventions/#toc_simple-routes) does not seem to do what is intended in the resulting Web app.

I have followed all the steps from the start of the guide to the end of that example, copying the code exactly, with two exceptions. First, I made a small change to `routes/favorites.js` to get around my lack of server backend, as shown here:

```
// import ajax from 'ic-ajax';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model() {
    // // the model is an Array of all of the posts
    // // fetched from this url
    // return ajax('/a/service/url/where/posts/live');
    return [{ title: 'Test 1' }, { title: 'Test 2' }];
  }
});
```

Second, I added an `{{outlet}}` to `templates/application.hbs` to show the `templates/favorites.hbs`:

```
<h1>{{appName}}</h1>
<h2>{{model.title}}</h2>

{{outlet}}
```

Unfortunately, going to `/favorites` while running `ember serve` just shows the same thing as `/`: the content of `application.hbs` (without the content of `favorites.hbs`). I would expect this to show a list with items "Test 1" and "Test 2".

Why does this not work? Am I doing something wrong?

When I run `ember -v` on my command line, I get this:

```
version: 1.13.6
node: 0.12.7
npm: 2.13.2
os: darwin x64
```

**Update:** Here is `templates/favorites.hbs`:

```
<ul>
{{#each controller as |item|}}
  <li>{{item.title}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here is `/router.js`:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend();

Router.map(function(){
  this.route('favorites');
});

export default Router;
```

I get a deprecation warning from the server:

```
DEPRECATION: Using `{{controller}}` or any path based on it ('my-app/templates/favorites.hbs' @ L2:C0) has been deprecated.
```

I also get four JSHint errors like this:

```
'Ember' is not defined.
```

Comment: Your model is returning a collection, and you are trying to access the property `title` off of the array.  You either need to iterate over the collection in the template using the `each` helper, or change your model hook to return a single object `return { title: 'Test 1' };`

Comment: And you should show your router as well, were there any errors?

Comment: @Kingpin2k I have added my router and template code and errors from the command line to the original post for you. The JavaScript console of the webpage gives this: `[Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'".` Replacing the array of items with a single item and changing `favorites.hbs` to just `<p>{{model.title}}</p>` does not seem to work either.

Comment: You can't iterate over the controller in ember-cli because of this: https://github.com/cibernox/ember-disable-proxy-controllers It's completely non-obvious.

Comment: @GarethJohnson Regarding the Content Security Policy violation: you need to allow it by adding `{ 'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'" },` to your `ENV.contentSecurityPolicy` in `config/environment.js`. More here: http://emberigniter.com/modify-content-security-policy-on-new-ember-cli-app/

Comment: @emberigniter Thanks, that removed the browser console error. (However, it did not fix the original problem.)

Comment: I am not sure what you could be missing. I recreated your app (see https://github.com/frank06/simpleroutes ) and when I visit `http://localhost:4200/favorites` I do see a list with "Test 1" and "Test 2". Can you double check with my repo?

Comment: @emberigniter Aha, your repo works! The key difference between mine and yours is the `router.js` file: you have some code with `config` and `location`, but the Ember guides' code does not. Now I know how to fix the problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem @GarethJohnson. I added an answer (which you may want to accept) because I'll probably remove that repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to navigate without a hash (`http://localhost:4200/favorites` instead of `http://localhost:4200/#/favorites`) make sure your router has its location type set:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType  // typically 'auto'
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('favorites');
});

export default Router;
```

Comment: Thanks again! This should really be included in the guides.

Answer (score 2):

Okay yeah this wasn't entirely obvious. Basically ember-cli has a package which disabled the proxy controllers: https://github.com/cibernox/ember-disable-proxy-controllers

This is related to:

> DEPRECATION: Using `{{controller}}` or any path based on it ('my-app/templates/favorites.hbs' @ L2:C0) has been deprecated.

You can't actually iterate over the controller when you use ember-cli like the guide suggests. Instead iterate over `model` (this is why your data isn't being rendered):

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
  <li>{{item.title}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

To get rid of:

```
'Ember' is not defined.
```

Add this at the top of the file it's being raised in:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
```

Comment: Thanks, this removed the deprecation warning and JSHint errors. Unfortunately, the content from `favorites.hbs` still does not appear at `http://localhost:4200/favorites`. (I suspect it is unrelated to iterating over the items, as replacing the array with a single object and changing the template to just `<p>{{model.title}}</p>` does not work either.)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `{{#each controller as |item|}}` try `{{#each item in model}}`